# Javascript подгружает не то, что выдает php

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

```
$.ajax({
              url: "http://...",
              type: "POST",
              data: $('#button33').serialize(),

              success: function(response) {

                //обработка успешной отправки
                alert(response)
               if (response=='succ_reg') { $('#succ_reg').css('top','25px').css('left','30px'); $('#registr').css({'top':'-500px'});  }

              },
              error: function(response) {
              alert('Не дозвонился до сервера');
                //обработка ошибок при отправке
             }
            });
```

В php

```
if ($login!='') echo $login;
```

Логин выводится. Проверял, отключал js.

В js

```
alert(response)
```

выводит пустоту.

Comment: чтобы решать подобные проблемы воспользуйтесь инструментом изображенным на картинке.

![картинко](http://i.stack.imgur.com/m977G.png)

Comment: @Радик Камалов, Пардон, а что у вас за элемент "**#button33**"? Боюсь что-либо предполагать, но название настораживает.

Comment: в Headers что я должен увидеть? В Preview: this request has no preview available. В response тоже.

Comment: Deonis, спасибо

Comment: @Радик Камалов, в headers посланные заголовки, убедитесь что они совпадают с вашими ожиданиями.

Answer (score 1):

cache: false используйте

Answer (score 0):

> Логин выводится. Проверял, отключал
> js.

для таких вещей есть например firephp + firebug

response это объект, а alert в качестве параметра использует строки. выводите через console.log(response);

Comment: Тоже пустая строка